# Deploying Django/Gunicorn to Nginx server with Python 3.4 found the wrong path for templates

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn

*Not sure if this question should be in ServerFault or StackOverflow but I think there are more people here.*

I have built a Django project called 'to_pm' and decided to put it on a VPS server which uses CentOs 7 as operating system. I want to deploy my Django project to Nginx server which I have already successfully setup and running on the server.

Originally I put my project to `/root/` as I am a newbie of linux system administration. Then I realized that as nginx is using `nginx` as its user and it needs to be the owner of my project folder and all its parent directories to access my project's static contents so I moved my project to `/www/` and change the owner of `/www/` to nginx:nginx. Then I was unable to access my website.

I get this error:(all the templates are in `to_pm/templates/` folder)

```
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django_jinja.loaders.FileSystemLoader:
/root/to_pm/templates/index.jinja (File does not exist)
```

and it shows my python path is:

```
Python Path:    
['/root/to_pm',
 '/usr/local/bin',
 '/usr/local/lib/python34.zip',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.4',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/plat-linux',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages']
```

see the attached picture:
[image]
How can I change to make my website up and running again? Do I need to change python path to /www/to_pm?
But I have `echo $PYTHONPATH` and nothing showed up. I don't know what to do from this point.

I am using Supervisor to run my project on Gunicorn Application server and I have checked my `supervisord.conf` file and I am sure there is no `/root/to_pm` path set in the file.

UPDATE:

I have narrowed down the problem. I think it's not a nginx issue because even if I turned Nginx off I still get the problem by using the initial IP and port without using port 80.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK it seems it is not the server's problem. There are some zombie processes in the backend of Centos running the project with the old path setting. After I killed those processes my site has went live.